# select files from setup location vb

Tags: vb.net

I work on my VB application on visual studio 2012
I created a button, On clicking it, it plays a file on my PC ("D:\My Project\Sound_01.wav")
so the code will be like that:

```
**Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Play("D:\My Project\Sound_01.wav")

End Sub**
```

My problem is that I need to make setup file for that app (using install shield 2015) and the file location will return error because the destination PC may not have the same location("D:\My Project\Sound_01.wav")

can anyone advise me how to do that?

Comment: Just include the sound file as part of your project, and reference it from inside the project folder.

Comment: can u explain more ?  explain on the mentioned example pls

Comment: please see Marco's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the file to your application path so you can use following:

```
  My.Computer.Audio.Play(Application.StartupPath & "\Sound_01.wav")
```